# TextButton doesn't update its label text

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have a TextButton inside a Stack and after I change its style and update its text I see no text in the Label. I even used the setText method in render(float delta) but no luck. I should mention that prior to calling the setText method the Stack also contained a picture, that completely covered the labell cell of the TextButton, which I simply removed.

Why isn't the text getting updated?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is successful, so I put it as a commentary, perhaps invalidate help you http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Stack.html#invalidate--

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's having this issue make sure you don't have the label set to hide(). I had it hidden for when a lock picture was displayed over the TextButton. Adding the line below solved my issue:

```
button.getLabel().addAction(Actions.show());
```